# Python cron jobs and JSON parsing

Tags: python, json, parsing, cron

I wrote this tiny script to pull the JSON feed from the [CitiBike website](http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json).

Here is the script:

```
import requests
import time

def executeCiti():
    r = requests.get("http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json") 
    print r.json()

    time.sleep(62)

while True:
    executeCiti()

exit()
```

Then I just run the script in terminal and output it to a .txt file like so: python citi_bike.py > output.txt

The end goal of what I would like by the end of this exercise is well formatted JSON data (with only select few of the pairs from each request), separated by each request.  I want it to be manageable so I can create visualizations from it.

My first question is: Is this an okay way to start what I'm trying to accomplish?

My second question is: Is there a better way to begin, so that the data came out like I want it as my end goal? In regard's to this question, I feel like I have already started taking a very roundabout way to getting to a cleaned up data set, even though this is only the first step.

Sorry if this is confusing. Please comment if you have any questions.

Comment: What does this have to do with cron?

Comment: This seems like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . What I'd say is that you have a good start, but you shouldn't sleep in the function which reads the data, since you might sometimes want to get data without sleeping. The actions are orthogonal. Also, `requests.get()` can almost certainly raise an exxception; for a long-standing task, you need to handle errors (say, temporarily lost internet connection) more gracefully.